# How to get every single VALUE by KEY while I'm looping through object?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with filled data, I know how to loop through it and how to get the key/value from it. However the problem I'm facing that I don't know how to loop second time for example through it with key[i] or value[i]. It's more likely that I'm looking for loop or something, but not sure how to loop till the end of object. Here's the small example what I have and what I want to do.

```
async function loadLanguages() {
        var languages = {
            lang: {
                lang: 'test1',
                lang2: 'test2'
            },
            lang2: {
                lang: 'test1',
                lang2: 'test2'
            },
        checkLanguages(languages);
    }

    async function checkLanguages(languagesObject) {
    for (const [key, value,] of Object.entries(languagesObject)) {
      // Maybe I could run for loop, 
      // but it's impossible to get something like languagesObject.size
      //(i mean till the last element)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is you expected output here?

Comment: I want to manipulate with data, to check for example if lang2.lang2 is test2 and etc

Comment: Please add the expected behavior. What exactly do you want to check inside the nested object. You can add another loop through `Object.entries(value)`?

Comment: also remove `async` you dont need it

Comment: Also post your expected `output object`. Or exactly what do you want to perform inside `checkLanguages`. You said `Maybe I could run for loop, `, but what do you want to do with the `loop`?

Comment: "_to check for example if lang2.lang2 is test2_" then why do you need to loop here.. you could simply do `if (languages.lang2.lang2 === "test2")` ?

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation, hard morning.. I actually want to run the loop through object and by every single key I have to check key's values and manipulate them.
@Ifaruki I need them, this is a small part of the code. palash probably === won't help or it will?

Comment: I think we are all here just confused on what is your expected output and why. You have to understand if you can't explain the problem, then no one can provide a solution for it, as there is no problem at first place. At best you will get solutions based on assumptions only, where some of them accidentally might be what you actually want, but in the process, you are just wasting others time in making assumptions for you. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

`for in` Loop is the better solution here

```
function loadLanguages() {
        var languages = {
            lang: {
                lang: 'test1',
                lang2: 'test2'
            },
            lang2: {
                lang: 'test1',
                lang2: 'test2'
            }
    }
        checkLanguages(languages)
}


function checkLanguages(languagesObject) {
  for (const key in languagesObject) {
    //if you want to check anything in main object
    console.log(languagesObject[key])
    //another loop to find key value in sub object
    for (const  subkey in languagesObject[key]) {
      console.log(languagesObject[key][subkey])
    }
  }
}
loadLanguages()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code, and looping through all the objects and checking whether `lang` is `test1` and if the condition is satisfied, then just doing console.log.

```js
function loadLanguages() {
        var languages = {
            lang: {
                lang: 'test1',
                lang2: 'test2'
            },
            lang2: {
                lang: 'test1',
                lang2: 'test2'
            },
            lang3: {
                lang: 'test2',
                lang2: 'test2'
            }
    }
    checkLanguages(languages)
}

function checkLanguages(languagesObject) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(languagesObject)) {
    if(value.lang === "test1") {
      console.log(`${key} language is Test1`);
    }
   }
}

loadLanguages()
```

If you want to loop through all the keys inside each object also, then use below utility. Here it'll loop through all the objects inside each object(considering only 2 levels as per your requirement) and checking if the value is matching with `test1` and just printing the `path`.

```js
function loadLanguages() {
        var languages = {
            lang: {
                lang: 'test1',
                lang2: 'test2'
            },
            lang2: {
                lang: 'test1',
                lang2: 'test2'
            },
            lang3: {
                lang: 'test2',
                lang2: 'test1'
            }
    }
    checkLanguages(languages)
}

function checkLanguages(languagesObject) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(languagesObject)) {
      for(const [innerKey, innerValue] of Object.entries(value)) {
        if(innerValue === "test1") {
          console.log(`${key}.${innerKey} is Test1`)
        }
      }
   }
}

loadLanguages()
```

Hope this helps